# Split text into sentences

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, text-segmentation

I wish to split text into sentences. Can anyone help me?

I also need to handle abbreviations. However my plan is to replace these at an earlier stage. Mr. -> Mister

```
import re  
import unittest    

class Sentences:

    def __init__(self,text):
        self.sentences = tuple(re.split("[.!?]\s", text))

class TestSentences(unittest.TestCase):

    def testFullStop(self):
        self.assertEquals(Sentences("X. X.").sentences, ("X.","X."))

    def testQuestion(self):
        self.assertEquals(Sentences("X? X?").sentences, ("X?","X?"))

    def testExclaimation(self):
        self.assertEquals(Sentences("X! X!").sentences, ("X!","X!"))

    def testMixed(self):
        self.assertEquals(Sentences("X! X? X! X.").sentences, ("X!", "X?", "X!", "X."))
```

Thanks,
Barry

EDIT: To start with, I would be happy to satisfy the four tests I've included above. This would help me understand better how regexs work. For now I can define a sentence as X. etc as defined in my tests.

Comment: Maybe you should describe what you consider a sentence.

Comment: Have a look at [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sentence Segmentation can be a very difficult task, especially when the text contains dotted abbreviations. it may require a use of lists of known abbreviations, or training classifier to recognize them.

I suggest you to use NLTK - it a suite of open source Python modules, designed for natural language processing.

You can read about Sentence Segmentation using NLTK **[here](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch03.html#sec-segmentation)**,
and decide for yourself if this tool fits you.

EDITED: or even simpler **[here](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.tokenize.punkt-module.html)** and here is the **[source code](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.tokenize.punkt-pysrc.html)**. 
This is The Punkt sentence tokenizer, included in NLTK.

Comment: Im using Python 3 and NLTK isnt built for this yet. I already have a large list of abbreviations and I believe I can handle this issue at an earlier stage.

Comment: Hmmm... maybe you can use the Punkt source code, and adjust it to Python 3? On second thought that would take a lot of work..

Comment: links in `EDITED` section are dead.