# Adding Each word in a String to a List?

Tags: string, list, python-3.x

Given the string

```
string1='apple purple orange brown'
```

How would I go about turning it into a list

```
list1=['apple','purple','orange','brown']
```

I thought I could do

```
string1='apple purple orange brown'
list1=[]
for item in string1:
     list1.append(item)
```

But that gives me a list of every single character of the string, not just the words. Would there be a way to split the string up by it's spaces, and then add it to the list?

Answer (score 1):

Use the split() method on String. It gives you a list:

```
>>> "Foo bar".split()
['Foo', 'bar']
```

If you want to split on something else than whitespace, just pass it to split:

```
>>> "Pipe|separated|values".split("|")
['Pipe', 'separated', 'values']
```

[Split knows even more tricks, like limiting the amount of splits](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Answer (score 0):

```
string1='apple purple orange brown'
list1=[]
list1.extend(string1.split(' '))
```

leaves

```
list1 == ['apple', 'purple', 'orange', 'brown']
```

The expression `string1.split(' ')` is itself a list of just the substrings that were separated by spaces, but you can use `extend` to add the result onto an existing list if you might have other content on that list.

---

If you need to deal with human language sentences, not just single spaces between words, then you might want to look into proper text segmentation as discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/a/7188852/20394

Answer (score 0):

```
string1='apple purple orange brown'
list1=string1.split()
```

Your list is in list1

Edit: The split function return a list